# Laravel pass array from form and parse in controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, forms, post

I have a array of inputs like bellow:

```html
<input type='hidden' name='sheepNames[]' value='bab' />
<input type='hidden' name='sheepNames[]' value='harry' />
<input type='hidden' name='sheepTitles[]' value='leader' />
<input type='hidden' name='sheepTitles[]' value='sheep' />
```

In my controller I need to loop through the arrays and save them in a database with columns `name` and `title`

```
bab | leader <br>
harry | sheep
```

```php
  $array = $request->get('sheepNames');

  foreach($array as $i => $item)
  {
    $tb_name->name= $array[$i];
    $tb_name->title= $request->get('sheepTitles')[$i];
  }
```

Tried numerous ways of accessing the array but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier to do this with a couple of arrays.

```
$names = $request->get('sheepNames');
$titles = $request->get('sheepTitles');

$max = count($names);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $max; $x ++){
    $tb_name[$x]['name']= $names[$x];
    $tb_name[$x]['title'] = $titles[$x];
}
```

I don't know what $tb_name is, but the way you had it above, it would keep getting written over, so I made it an array to make the point.

Also - you need to put some error check on the count of titles to make sure they == names, else you will have a broken index on the titles array possibly.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: i'm getting null. I'm using laravel 6